# How to display multiple objects in a single row in my UITableVIew?

Tags: ipad, uitableview

I want to display three items in my UITableView's row. What should be best and efficient way to do this. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

It shows you how to customize many aspects of a UITableView (and cells too).